# parse a csv file and redirect the full row to another file when a specific column is blank

Tags: awk

Situation: I have a csv file with multple columns

Need: Using a bash script, extract rows where "Severity" is blank and add the full row details to a new csv file

I tried the following but couldn't get it to work:

```
awk -F -vpos_sev=${severity_column}, '!length(${vpos_sev})' ${source_log_file} | tee -a ${no_severity_logs_file}
```

where:

- severity_column=3 # the column with the severity setting
- source_log_file= yep.. the csv source log file to parse
- no_severity_logs_file=the file to hold the parsed results where the Severity is blank i.e. not INFO, WARNING or ERROR

Example source file -

```
Header 1,Header 2,Severity,Header 4,Header 5
col1txt1,col2txt1,INFO,col4txt1,col5txt1
col1txt2,col2txt2,WARNING,col4txt2,col5txt2
col1txt3,col2txt3,ERROR,col4txt3,col5txt3
col1txt4,col2txt4,INFO,col4txt4,col5txt4
col1txt5,col2txt5,WARNING,col4txt5,col5txt5
col1txt6,col2txt6,ERROR,col4txt6,col5txt6
col1txt7,col2txt7,,col4txt7,col5txt7
col1txt8,col2txt8,INFO,col4txt8,col5txt8
col1txt9,col2txt9,INFO,col4txt9,col5txt9
col1txt10,col2txt10,ERROR,col4txt10,col5txt10
col1txt11,col2txt11,WARNING,col4txt11,col5txt11
col1txt12,col2txt12,WARNING,col4txt12,col5txt12
col1txt13,col2txt13,WARNING,col4txt13,col5txt13
col1txt14,col2txt14,WARNING,col4txt14,col5txt14
col1txt15,col2txt15,,col4txt15,col5txt15
col1txt16,col2txt16,,col4txt16,col5txt16
col1txt17,col2txt17,,col4txt17,col5txt17
col1txt18,col2txt18,,col4txt18,col5txt18
col1txt19,col2txt19,,col4txt19,col5txt19
col1txt20,col2txt20,,col4txt20,col5txt20
col1txt21,col2txt21,,col4txt21,col5txt21
col1txt22,col2txt22,,col4txt22,col5txt22
col1txt23,col2txt23,,col4txt23,col5txt23
col1txt24,col2txt24,,col4txt24,col5txt24
col1txt25,col2txt25,,col4txt25,col5txt25
col1txt26,col2txt26,,col4txt26,col5txt26
col1txt27,col2txt27,,col4txt27,col5txt27
```

Expected output file:

```
Header 1,Header 2,Severity,Header 4,Header 5
col1txt7,col2txt7,,col4txt7,col5txt7
col1txt15,col2txt15,,col4txt15,col5txt15
col1txt16,col2txt16,,col4txt16,col5txt16
col1txt17,col2txt17,,col4txt17,col5txt17
col1txt18,col2txt18,,col4txt18,col5txt18
col1txt19,col2txt19,,col4txt19,col5txt19
col1txt20,col2txt20,,col4txt20,col5txt20
col1txt21,col2txt21,,col4txt21,col5txt21
col1txt22,col2txt22,,col4txt22,col5txt22
col1txt23,col2txt23,,col4txt23,col5txt23
col1txt24,col2txt24,,col4txt24,col5txt24
col1txt25,col2txt25,,col4txt25,col5txt25
col1txt26,col2txt26,,col4txt26,col5txt26
col1txt27,col2txt27,,col4txt27,col5txt27
```

Comment: `grep ',,' ${source_log_file}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues:

1. You forgot to define the field separator. Fix: use `-F,` instead of `-F`.
2. `-vpos_sev=...` assigns `awk` variable `pos_sev` but your script uses variable `vpos_sev`. Fix: use `pos_sev` variable in your `awk` script.
3. In `awk` scripts you refer to field `n` with `$n`, not `${n}`. Fix: use `$pos_sev`.

Plus: in your case curly braces around shell variables are useless; they are needed when there is an ambiguity, like when you want to concatenate string `bar` to the expansion of variable `foo`: `${foo}bar`. But you should double-quote their expansion, just in case you have spaces in your file names. Fix: use `"$source_log_file"` instead of `${source_log_file}`.

All in all with minimal modifications:

```
awk -F, -v pos_sev="$severity_column" '!length($pos_sev)' "$source_log_file" |
  tee -a "$no_severity_logs_file"
```

Comment: Thanks @Renaud.  I've included the corrected function but it still writes all lines to the output file regardless of the content of the severity column `function write_no_severity_logs_to_file () {
msg "Writing \"No Severity\" logs to \"${no_severity_logs_file}\" for future analysis."
# copy header row to the ${no_severity_logs_file} file
head -n 1 ${source_log_file} >> ${no_severity_logs_file}
# add lines with blank severities to ${no_severity_logs_file} file
awk -F, -v pos_sev="$severity_column" '!length($pos_sev)' "$source_log_file" >> "$no_severity_logs_file"
}` Any ideas?

Comment: If you redirect the output with `>> "$no_severity_logs_file"` you **append** the new output to the previous one. Are you sure you look at the new content? Aren't you looking at the old content from your old tries?

Answer (score 4):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F, 'NR == 1 || $3 == ""' file.csv

Header 1,Header 2,Severity,Header 4,Header 5
col1txt7,col2txt7,,col4txt7,col5txt7
col1txt15,col2txt15,,col4txt15,col5txt15
col1txt16,col2txt16,,col4txt16,col5txt16
col1txt17,col2txt17,,col4txt17,col5txt17
col1txt18,col2txt18,,col4txt18,col5txt18
col1txt19,col2txt19,,col4txt19,col5txt19
col1txt20,col2txt20,,col4txt20,col5txt20
col1txt21,col2txt21,,col4txt21,col5txt21
col1txt22,col2txt22,,col4txt22,col5txt22
col1txt23,col2txt23,,col4txt23,col5txt23
col1txt24,col2txt24,,col4txt24,col5txt24
col1txt25,col2txt25,,col4txt25,col5txt25
col1txt26,col2txt26,,col4txt26,col5txt26
col1txt27,col2txt27,,col4txt27,col5txt27
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to look outside of `awk`, the `csvgrep` utility from the useful [`csvkit` package](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (An essential part of the toolbox for working with CSV data in scripts and a command line) makes it trivial:

```bash
csvgrep -r '^$' -c Severity input.csv > output.csv
```

Don't even need to know the column number if the file has a header line with column names like your example does.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
Header 1,Header 2,Severity,Header 4,Header 5
col1txt1,col2txt1,INFO,col4txt1,col5txt1
col1txt2,col2txt2,WARNING,col4txt2,col5txt2
col1txt3,col2txt3,ERROR,col4txt3,col5txt3
col1txt4,col2txt4,INFO,col4txt4,col5txt4
col1txt5,col2txt5,WARNING,col4txt5,col5txt5
col1txt6,col2txt6,ERROR,col4txt6,col5txt6
col1txt7,col2txt7,,col4txt7,col5txt7
col1txt8,col2txt8,INFO,col4txt8,col5txt8
col1txt9,col2txt9,INFO,col4txt9,col5txt9
col1txt10,col2txt10,ERROR,col4txt10,col5txt10
col1txt11,col2txt11,WARNING,col4txt11,col5txt11
col1txt12,col2txt12,WARNING,col4txt12,col5txt12
col1txt13,col2txt13,WARNING,col4txt13,col5txt13
col1txt14,col2txt14,WARNING,col4txt14,col5txt14
col1txt15,col2txt15,,col4txt15,col5txt15
col1txt16,col2txt16,,col4txt16,col5txt16
col1txt17,col2txt17,,col4txt17,col5txt17
col1txt18,col2txt18,,col4txt18,col5txt18
col1txt19,col2txt19,,col4txt19,col5txt19
col1txt20,col2txt20,,col4txt20,col5txt20
col1txt21,col2txt21,,col4txt21,col5txt21
col1txt22,col2txt22,,col4txt22,col5txt22
col1txt23,col2txt23,,col4txt23,col5txt23
col1txt24,col2txt24,,col4txt24,col5txt24
col1txt25,col2txt25,,col4txt25,col5txt25
col1txt26,col2txt26,,col4txt26,col5txt26
col1txt27,col2txt27,,col4txt27,col5txt27
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){arr[$i]=i};print;next}$(arr["Severity"])==""' file.txt > no_severity.txt
```

creates (or overwrites) `no_severity.txt` with following content

```
Header 1,Header 2,Severity,Header 4,Header 5
col1txt7,col2txt7,,col4txt7,col5txt7
col1txt15,col2txt15,,col4txt15,col5txt15
col1txt16,col2txt16,,col4txt16,col5txt16
col1txt17,col2txt17,,col4txt17,col5txt17
col1txt18,col2txt18,,col4txt18,col5txt18
col1txt19,col2txt19,,col4txt19,col5txt19
col1txt20,col2txt20,,col4txt20,col5txt20
col1txt21,col2txt21,,col4txt21,col5txt21
col1txt22,col2txt22,,col4txt22,col5txt22
col1txt23,col2txt23,,col4txt23,col5txt23
col1txt24,col2txt24,,col4txt24,col5txt24
col1txt25,col2txt25,,col4txt25,col5txt25
col1txt26,col2txt26,,col4txt26,col5txt26
col1txt27,col2txt27,,col4txt27,col5txt27
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that `,` is field separator (`FS`), then when processing 1st line I create array `arr` to map column name (header) to column number, then `print` line as is and go to `next` line. For all following lines I get these for which column with header `Severity` is empty string. Note that this solution will for `Severity` being any column, however this complicate it in comparison to assuming Severity is 3rd column.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*